# Personal Portfolio - Layout and basic functionality

Tags: javascript, css, html5

```js
function openav() {
    document.getElementById('sidenav').style.width = '18%';
    document.getElementById('open-btn').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('main').style.marginRight = '18%';
    document.getElementById('hero-header').style.marginRight = '18%';
    document.getElementById('footer').style.marginRight = '18%';
}

function closenav() {
    document.getElementById('sidenav').style.width = '0%';
    document.getElementById('open-btn').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('main').style.marginRight = '0%';
    document.getElementById('hero-header').style.marginRight = '0%';
    document.getElementById('footer').style.marginRight = '0%';
}
```

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}


header {
    transition: .5s;
}

.hero-bg {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: #232323;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 1%;
    transition: .5s;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#open-btn {
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 190%;
    top: 1%;
    right: 1%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#sidenav {
    background: #232323;
    opacity: .95;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: .5s;
}

#sidenav a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 135%;
    padding: 4%;
    transition: .3s;
}

#sidenav a:hover {
    color: lightgray;
    font-size: 130%;
    padding: 4%;
}

#sidenav .close-btn {
    text-align: left;
    top: 0;
}

main {
    transition: .5s;
}

main i {
    font-size: 190%;
}

#about {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 4%;
}

#services {
    background: #232323;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.service-item {
    padding: 4%;
}

#portfolio {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    text-align: center;
}

.portfolio-item {
    padding: 4%;
}

#contact {
    background: #232323;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.contact-item {
    padding: 4%;
}

.contact-item a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20%;
}

.contact-text {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

footer {
    background: #232323;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4%;
    transition: .5s;
}

.footer-text, a {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://avatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net/initials/BK-0.png">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b8c38afa05.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <title>Braeden King</title>
</head>
<body>

<header id="hero-header">

    <div class="hero-bg">
        <div class="hero-text">
            <h1>Braeden King</h1>
            <p>Front End Web Developer</p>
        </div>

        <div class="hero-button">
            <a id="open-btn" onclick="openav()">&#9776;</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav id="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closenav()" class="close-btn">X</a>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </nav>

</header>



<main id="main">

    <section id="about">
        <div class="about-item">
            <article>
                <h1>Hi There! I'm Braeden King.</h1>            
                <p>I am a Front End Web Developer </p>
            </article>
        </div>
    </section>


    <section id="services">
        <div class="service-item">
            <article>
                <h2>Web Design</h2>
                <i class="fas fa-pen-fancy"></i>
                <hr>                                    
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In placeat ipsa, labore eaque inventore, ullam molestiae nesciunt tempore quis corrupti sequi explicabo accusamus sed, recusandae eum veniam eius qui est.</p>
            </article>
        </div>

        <div class="service-item">
            <article>
                <h2>Web Development</h2>
                <i class="fas fa-code"></i>
                <hr>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, autem obcaecati pariatur consequatur corrupti commodi eaque nostrum quo iusto numquam nisi dolorem voluptatem omnis repellat tempora eligendi quis suscipit laborum.</p>
            </article>
        </div>

        <div class="service-item">
            <article>
                <h2>UI / UX Design</h2>
                <i class="fas fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
                <hr>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis corrupti dicta maiores ab ex facilis iure tempora, maxime amet nesciunt labore vel odit architecto delectus soluta repellat rerum, mollitia placeat!</p>
            </article>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="portfolio">
        <div class="portfolio-item">
            <article>
                <h2>Tip Calculator</h2>
                <a href="#"></a>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore dolores asperiores ad culpa sapiente quisquam dolorum quia dolor maxime nam ipsam accusantium, ducimus deleniti, voluptatem quod! Ut nobis eum voluptates.</p>
            </article>
        </div>

        <div class="portfolio-item">
            <article>
                <h2>Project</h2>
                <a href=""></a>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsa totam sed pariatur consequatur mollitia nobis maxime? Iste, perspiciatis rem? Dolorem molestiae quibusdam sequi ipsum consectetur, commodi accusamus iure veritatis aspernatur.</p>
            </article>
        </div>

        <div class="portfolio-item">
            <article>
                <h2>Project</h2>
                <a href="#"></a>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora modi numquam provident molestiae impedit, eius fuga aliquam ratione vitae deserunt ad saepe placeat rem consequatur laboriosam doloribus? Enim, quis non.</p>
            </article>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="contact">
        <div class="contact-item">
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-dribbble"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        </div>

        <div class="contact-item">
            <div class="contact-text">
                <article>
                    <h2>Contact Me!</h2>
                    <p>I'm always looking for new opportunities to gain experience.</p>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="contact-item">
            <a href="mailto: "><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
            <a href="tel:"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i></a>
        </div>
    </section>

</main>

<footer id="footer">

    <hr>

    <div class="footer-text">
        <article>
            <h3>Braeden King</h3>
            <a href="mailto:">example@example.com</a>
            <a href="tel:">+1 (800) 429-6666  <a>
            <p>Copyright <i class="fas fa-copyright"></i> 2020 by Braeden King</p>
        </article>
    </div>

</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Just wondering if anyone could give me tips/pointers/feedback on the code i have written here for a personal portfolio. Thanks (im new to this site so take it easy on me lol)
:)

Comment: When you vote to close or down vote, please leave a comment if there are no comments about why you so voted.

Comment: Can you please add a description of what the code does, a sentence or 2 after the title.

Comment: @pacmaninbw the HTML and CSS is just the layout and styles of my portfolio the javascript controls the sidenav and how the page moves in relation to the sidenav being opened. Sorry for not stating that in the title. I'm new to stack exchange.

Comment: @pacmaninbw It's a bit thin on description, but considering it's a portfolio page, not much description is required.

Comment: It looks unfinished though.

Comment: @Mast I've retracted my VTC, that is the best I can do. Neither down vote is mine.

Comment: @Mast sorry for the late response. But it is a little bit unfinished but this is just me trying to get tips for what I should maybe add or get rid of before actually finishing up the project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaScript unnecessarily contains information that belongs in the style sheet. It would be much easier to have the JavaScript simply set/remove a class (for example, on the body) and put the styles into the style sheet.

```
function openav() {
   document.body.classList.add("open-nav");
}

function closenav() {
    document.body.classList.remove("open-nav");
}
```

```
.open-nav #sidenav {
    width: 18%;
}

.open-nav #open-btn {
   display: none;
}

.open-nav #main, .open-nav #hero-header, .open-nav #footer {
    margin-right: 18%;
}
```